# Buffered Writer - newLine not doing anything

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a HTML file in Java, however the bw.newLine(); is not working. It's all displaying in one line.

```
        File f = new File("quote.html");
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));

        bw.write("Client                 : " + clientID + " - " + creditLimit[1]);

        bw.newLine();        

        bw.write("Service Code           : " + serviceCode);

        bw.newLine();

        bw.write("Number of Launches     : " + numberOfLaunches);

        bw.newLine();

        bw.write("Orbit Type             : " + orbitType);

        bw.close();
```

It's all just displaying in one line.

Comment: How do you display tghe data? Did you check the type of newline character being written? Note that per the JavaDoc "The line separator string is defined by the system property line.separator, and is not necessarily a single newline ('\n') character."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
bw.newLine(); // write a platform-dependent new line character (\n for unix)
```

For HTML you need use the `<br/>` HTML element:

```
bw.write("<br/>");
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML newlines in the source code are not rendered. To display a newline in HTML your need to add the `<br>` tag